# Capturing errors in sublime build file using regex in Sublime Text 3

Tags: regex, build, system, sublimetext3, capture

I'm trying to capture the errors I get when coding in Sublime Text 3. The errors look like this:

```
filename.extension:lineNumber: error: "The error message"
            Code that = is.wrong();
                          ^  <--Arrow pointing to the error
```

My regex capturing code is

```
"result_file_regex": "^(...*?):([0-9]*): error: (.*)"
```

which according to [this](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/reference/build_systems/configuration.html) documentation should be correct, except there is no column number to capture.

Whenever I try to run a wrong code using this regex it errors to the sublime output

```
str expected, not dict
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What is the input that it's erroring on exactly?   You could realistically make the line / column number optional with a ? ([0-9]*)?

Comment: I don't think it's allowed to wrap the RegEx in slashes as you would *normally* do

Comment: Please [edit] your question to add more detail - please create a [mcve]. Add sample code (including the language) and the contents of your build system so we can test its behavior. Please state where exactly the error is printed, and if anything else is there as well. You should also indicate where you've put the `"result_file_regex"` setting. Basically, you should allow us to completely recreate what you're doing.

Comment: And @idleberg is correct, there should be no slashes in your regex unless it's actually part of the regular expression.

Comment: @MattDMo the slashes don't seem to affect anything. Removing them gives the same error. Also, the same error is given in Python so I assume it is irrelevant of programming language.

Comment: Try `"result_file_regex": "^(..[^:]*):([0-9]+):?([0-9]+)?:? (.*)$"`.

Comment: @GerardRoche No good. Same error.

Comment: Enable logging `Menu > View > Show Console`. In the console: `sublime.log_commands(True); sublime.log_result_regex(True); sublime.log_build_systems(True);` Then show the full content of the output when running the build, including the errors.

Comment: @GerardRoche Updated with log.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **result_file_regex**
>       A Perl-style regular expression to capture up to four fields of error information from a results view, namely: filename, line number, column number and error message. Use groups in the pattern to capture this information. The filename field and the line number field are required.
>
> — http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/reference/build_systems/configuration.html?highlight=result_file_regex

*It says "result_file_regex" in the docs, but that's wrong, the key for builds "file_regex".*

How do we match something like:

```
filename.extension:lineNumber: error: "The error message"
```

Let's start with the simplest match, the filename and the line number:

```
"file_regex": "^([^:]+):([0-9]+):.*$"
```

The above matches the filename and the line number (two matches).

```
"file_regex": "^([^:]+):([0-9]+):([0-9]+)?.*$"
```

The above matches the filename, line number and an optional column number.

```
"file_regex": "^([^:]+):([0-9]+):([0-9]+)? error: (.+)$"
```

The above matches all four elements: the filename, line number, column number (optional), and the error message.

Comment: This is great! Thank you so much!